# How to append values to a nested div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="myDiv1">
<table>
<tr id="row">
</table>
</div>
<div id="myDiv2">
<table>
<tr id="row">
</table>
</div>
```

Here I need to append different `'<td>'`s into these two . I have tried this code 
**$('#row').append()**
but its only putting `'<td>'`s into the row of **myDiv1**.
Can anyone help me to do this.

Comment: ID attribute should be unique in DOM.

Comment: use class instead of id

Comment: Browsers store a fast ID-lookup as a single dictionary entry (of ID vs a single element). This means jQuery and Javascript can only find the first match by ID. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple erros in your markup:

1. No closing `<tr>`-tags
2. Non-Unique ID's

So the ID-Attribute has to be unique in its scope.
See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) for further information.

Your mark-up should be looking like this:

```
<div id="myDiv1">
    <table>
        <tr class="row">
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="myDiv2">
    <table>
        <tr class="row">
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

With the right markup your jQuery just works fine:

```
$('.row').append('<td>test</td>');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uLzpb2dp/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should change the ID attribute to a class.

But why are you using two tables? maybe you need to clean the html and make it as bellow.

```
<div id="myDiv1">
    <table>
        <tr class="row">
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```